Kong upgrade 2.8 to 3.6 issue
I'm upgrading kong gateway and facing an issue while running the image

old configuration docker file: kong/kong-gateway:2.8.1.1
and upgraded to: kong:3.3.1-alpine

The image is built without any issues named kong-upg and I created another docker-compose file
with kong service:
services:
  kong-gateway:
    image: kong-upg
    container_name: kong-gateway
    user: kong
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      KONG_DATABASE: "off"

But I'm getting the following error:
kong-gateway                        | 2024/04/29 12:32:56 [error] 24#0: init_by_lua error: attempt to compare string with number
kong-gateway                        | stack traceback:
kong-gateway                        |   [C]: in function 'sort'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/errors.lua:28: in function 'sorted_keys'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/errors.lua:229: in function 'schema_violation'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/schema/plugin_loader.lua:28: in function 'load_subschema'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:265: in function 'load_plugin'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:312: in function 'load_plugin_schemas'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:619: in function 'init'
kong-gateway                        |   init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
kong-gateway                        | nginx: [error] init_by_lua error: attempt to compare string with number
kong-gateway                        | stack traceback:
kong-gateway                        |   [C]: in function 'sort'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/errors.lua:28: in function 'sorted_keys'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/errors.lua:229: in function 'schema_violation'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/schema/plugin_loader.lua:28: in function 'load_subschema'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:265: in function 'load_plugin'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/db/dao/plugins.lua:312: in function 'load_plugin_schemas'
kong-gateway                        |   /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/init.lua:619: in function 'init'
kong-gateway                        |   init_by_lua:3: in main chunk
kong-gateway                        | Error: /usr/local/share/lua/5.1/kong/cmd/start.lua:101: failed to start nginx (exit code: 1)
kong-gateway                        | 
kong-gateway                        |   Run with --v (verbose) or --vv (debug) for more details
kong-gateway exited with code 1

Has anyone faced this issue before? Tried different images and still got the same issues.

I found that the issue was in the custom plugin formatting, as the error being thrown from kong is misleading as it is not referring to specific code in the custom plugin.
I needed to adjust the formatting in the plugin handler to be as follows:
local typedefs = require "kong.db.schema.typedefs"

return {
    name = "api-key-auth",
    fields = {
        { consumer = typedefs.no_consumer },
        { config = { type = "record", fields = { }, }, },
    },
}

